# Google Play Release App Updates With Staged Rollout Has No Updates For More Than Two weeks

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have a new app release for my App In which I've rolled out to 50% of my base. This is my first time to apply staged rollout, I'm a little bit confused why my app dashboard has no updates for this release since two weeks!

50% of my app base is about 60k users. There is only 1 single new install. AFAIK this dashboard counts the new users as well as the existing users who update the App. From previous releases the number of updates/installs is much more the current situation, the only difference is that I used to apply for full release.

As per documentation, it will take time for the full group to receive the updates, but the documentation never gives an estimate. I have been waiting for 2 weeks and I have only one single install.
If there is anything I shall take care of, any recommendations. Below are screenshots for my dashboard.[image]

Comment: Are you using managed publishing?

Comment: Yes we use managed publishing

Comment: Is the update waiting in managed publishing by any chance?

Comment: @user14678216 No, there is no updates waiting in managed publishing.